Error: pragma solidity >0.4.0 <= 0.9.0; ParserError: Expected ';' but got '}'
Please help me the error: from solidity:
ParserError: Expected ';' but got '}'
Here is the code:
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
    return true; maxPriorityFeePerGas
  }

I am using pragma solidity >0.4.0 <= 0.9.0;
Thank you!

why have you written maxPriorityFeePerGas at the end? just remove it and it's fine.
